# Turn off email validation

Tags: angularjs

I have the following piece of html/angular

```
<input type="email" data-ng-model="myEmailVar" />
{{ myEmailVar }}
```

Now the problem is angular has an auto-validator for emails that won't set myEmailVar unless it passes correctly. So for instance if I enter "name" myEmailVar will not be set. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bFVsW/ (enter the word test, then enter test@test.test)

Now, I want to run my own validation, but also support mobile. If I use type="email" some mobile browsers switch the keyboard layout to make inputting an address easier (such as the @ symbol). So I can't switch it to type="text". What i'd like to do is override the angular email validator or just turn it off completely as I'll be handling my own validation. Is that possible?

Comment: Add html5 `novalidate` attribute to the form.

Comment: currently you could not disable or override it so you have to use input type=text and make your own directive for custom validatoin

Comment: @Stewie, can you provide me a fiddle of that working? I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @Stewie I just tried that in this fiddle and got nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/bFVsW/1/

Comment: I've just took a look at the source code. The email input type returns undefined unless the email regexp (custom or default one) doesn't match the value. So maybe you could go with a workaround, by using ng-show/hide to show/hide different input (with different input type) depending on whether it's a mobile or not.

Comment: How do I define a custom email regexp? Also won't switching the inputs leave mobile with the issue?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407546/how-to-disable-angulars-type-email-validation

Comment: That does not work. My input is not within a form.

Answer (score 5):

On HTML5 you can use the form's attribute novalidate to disable browser's validation:

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type="email"/>
</form>
```

Or you can use `type="text"`

Comment: Please read the comments above for why this will not work for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For any body who is still searching for an answer, I found the answer in this stack overflow answer: **[How to disable angulars type=email validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407546/how-to-disable-angulars-type-email-validation/18781558#18781558)**

Essentially you can add your own custom directive that disables the default angular validators.

```
angular.module('app').directive('disableValidators', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            var validator = function(value){
                return value;
            };

            // replace other validators with our own
            ctrl.$parsers = [validator];
            ctrl.$formatters = [validator];
        }
    }
});
```

Another answer in that same thread presents a more detailed answer: **[How to disable angulars type=email validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407546/how-to-disable-angulars-type-email-validation/19527142#19527142)**

Edit: This solution worked for me in the past, but no longer worked when I upgrade from angular 1.2.X to 1.3.X. It works, however, with a few minor tweaks:

```
angular.module('app').directive('disableValidators', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var validator = function(value) {
                return value;
            };

            // replace the email validators
            ctrl.$validators = {email: validator};
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : This does NOT work ... well at least not in a way you'd like it to.  Adding ng-non-bindable to the form or any input breaks ALL binding.  So, your ng-model in the inputs won't work anymore. Sorry ....

ng-non-bindable is the answer to this problem.  See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387233/75644

Comment: I do not have a form element to put the ng-non-bindable on. I only have the input element.

Comment: @MathewBerg Why don't you have a form element?

Comment: Put it on the input element. "<input type="email" name="email" ng-non-bindable>".  Basically, you can put it on any HTML element that angularjs "hijacks".

Answer (score -3):

Simple solution: init field with type `'text'` and change type to `'email'` by timeout. In this case angularjs won't add email validator and you will have the email keyboard.

```
<input type="{{type}}" />

$scope.type = 'text';  
$timeout(function() { 
    $scope.type = 'email'; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44pc5j8L/