# Have AngularJs update {{binding}} as the user types in input[email]

Tags: angularjs, validation

Angular only updates the model from an `input[email]` after the user has entered a valid email address. How can I add a `{{binding}}` somewhere on the page that will update with the email value **as the user types** -- even before the user has typed in a valid email address?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form name="MyForm" novalidate>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="contact.name" /><br/>
            Name as you type: {{contact.name}}<br/>
            Email: <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="contact.email" /><br/>
            Email as you type: {{contact.email}} (doesn't work)<br/>
            Also doesn't work: {{$document.forms.MyForm.elements.email.value}}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.contact = {};
}
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nt7Gr/1/)

The name updates in real-time like I want, but the email doesn't.

I'd like to leave the email validation enabled. I just need some way to bind the un-validated `input[email]` text, so it updates as the user types.

**Update 2014/7/8**

I'd like to add an explicit requirement that the `type="email"` remains unchanged. I do not want to change the semantics of the markup to workaround a limitation of the framework. If need be, I'd rather pull in a complementary dependency (such as jQuery) to shim in the needed functionality.

I'm not opposed to handling validation in the controller — as suggested by rageandqq and  charlietfl — if it could be done easily. Looking around though, [it looks like it could be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527142/27581) (given my requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I've come up with so far is to use jQuery to listen for the `input` change and update an object on `$scope` that I've called `formRaw`. It works. Still, I'm hoping someone will come along and show me a better way.

The updated example:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form name="MyForm" novalidate>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="contact.name" /><br/>
            Name as you type: {{contact.name}}<br/>
            Email: <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="contact.email" /><br/>
            Email Model: {{contact.email}}<br/>
            Email Form: {{formRaw.email}}
            {{q}}
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.contact = {};
    $scope.formRaw = {};

    $('input[type=email]').on('keyup change', function () {
        var input = $(this);
        $scope.formRaw[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
        $scope.$digest(); // FIXME: there's got to be a better way
    });
}
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nt7Gr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

That is how angularjs works. If you use `<input type="email" />` angular is not going to bind your input till input will be valid in this case value must be a proper e-mail address.

please read more here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1426

Comment: Even if it's not the way angularjs "works", surely there's some workaround to achieve the effect I'm asking for. Instead of binding to the model, can I bind to an expression that resolves to the DOM value?

Comment: of course yes use rageandqq solution type="text" instead of "email"

Comment: @MichaelKropat look in angular source and you can borrow their validation regex to put in your validation method

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the suggestion. I updated the question with why that might be tricky for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The `type="email"` attribute on your E-mail input is what is causing the DOM binding to mess up.
Changing it to `type="text"` works allows your `{{contact.email}}` to display correctly.

[Edited JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nt7Gr/2/)

Comment: I'd like the keep the email validation in place, so this is not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the way AngularJS is built. I would recommend simply placing e-mail validation logic in your controller.