# Adding class dynamically based on condition in angular js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In one of my application, I have a requirement to add a specific class when it has any data irrespective of it's input type (email, text) using AngularJS:

In [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yJ99qcZBA6ELphvyRSp?p=preview) plunk, just type any thing in the text box to change the border color.

***code for reference***

```
<body ng-app="">
    <input type='text' ng-model='Custom' ng-class="{red : Custom.length}">
    <label ng-bind='Custom'></label>
</body>
```

In a similar way I want it for all the input types.

In case of email field. When user typed wrong email, it's not working because model will not get value when it is invalid.

Comment: Similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619437/have-angularjs-update-binding-as-the-user-types-in-inputemail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular not binding value to model until model is valid so in case of input type filed lengthwill be 0 until you type in proper email. But you can do that using $viewValue value please see demo below

```css
.red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <form name="myform">
    <input type='text' ng-model='Custom' ng-class="{red : Custom.length}">
    <input type='email' ng-model='email' ng-class="{red : myform.email.$viewValue}" name="email">

    <label ng-bind='Custom'></label>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because until the input contains a valid email address ng-model is empty.

One way to overcome it is to check the $viewValue variable like this:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <input name="email" type='email' ng-model='email' 
           ng-class="{red : myForm.email.$viewValue.length}">
</form>
```